# Protecting a question does not work with exactly 15000 reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, privileges, protected-questions

Today I got to 15000 reputation on Super User. I received the notification that I could now protect questions (eligible for protection as per the FAQ).

Interestingly enough, it didn't work. I just couldn't find the link. So [I brought it up on Meta.SU](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3492/48078).

It turns out: **At exactly 15000 reputation, you can't protect a question**. If you are at 15001, it works though. Probably the internal check uses a `reputation > 15000` check instead of `reputation ≥ 15000`. Should be easy to fix.

Comment: … could also be that this is an issue for all other privileges?

Comment: possibly ... Ill have a quick look

Comment: yeah .. I changed in 12 other spots as well

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image: crisis averted]

Crisis has been averted :) my bug.

Comment: You just wanted to show off that awful color scheme.

Comment: So is this how you guys communicate at SE corporate?  By tossing meta comments over the cubicle walls? :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah ... either that or the twitters :)

Comment: "MinAgeBeforeAllowingProtectInDays". So I'm guessing you guys don't need to comment your variables

Comment: @Jarrod's right, [Obsidian](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian) is a much nicer theme.

Comment: @TimStone I dunno I have a soft spot for Vibrent Ink http://alternateidea.com/blog/articles/2006/1/3/textmate-vibrant-ink-theme-and-prototype-bundle must be my old Ruby days

Comment: Also, that code made me realize it's [possible to protect answers](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/posts/683/revisions) (if you're a mod)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I noticed that too, but the option doesn't show up in the mod menu... how did you pull that off?

Comment: well protecting answers is clearly a bug :) fixing @nhinkle

Comment: @waffles, I'm guessing from that link that the theme you use isn't for VS - do you use a similar one in VS (if you use VS that is!) that's on t'internet anywhere, it's very soothing on the eyes! =) On another note, wrapping `!post.IsProtected && post.IsQuestion` as a property `bool IsProtectable` - overkill? I'm curious what fix you went for... duplicating the `post.IsQuestion` check, mass refactor, or something else entirely? (Only because I'm always interested in seeing how other people tweak their code)

Comment: @Rob already restructured that code to fix the bug Michael raised, I use a self modified version of http://studiostyl.es/schemes/vibrant-ink in vs 2010

Comment: @waffles - theme downloading as I type - thankee :)